# ALR-H450 barcode reader

Tags: java, android-studio

I am attempting to activate the barcode scanner on an Alien ALR-H450, but I keep getting an error that a semi-colon is expected. It shows an error for this line:

public void onBarcodeRead(String barcode)

it expects a (;) after onDarcodeRead and after barcode.

full code:

```
public BarcodeReader barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();


public void start(BarcodeCallback callback){
    @Override
    public void onBarcodeRead(String barcode) {
        String detectedBarcode = barcode;
        // Scan will automatically stop after successfully scanning a barcode
    };
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Can some point out what I may be missing to get that error?

Comment: Why is this function in another function?

Comment: is was taken from the Dev guide.   barcodeReader.start(new BarcodeCallback() {
 @Override
 public void onBarcodeRead(String barcode) {
 String detectedBarcode = barcode;
 // Scan will automatically stop after successfully scanning a barcode
 }
 }
);

Comment: _This_ code looks like it could work. The code in your question is just wrong, so what exactly did you change and why?

Comment: I get about 20 errors starting with <identifier> expected when I use the code directly from the Developer's guide.